# How to read data from JavaScript by using Java code

Tags: java, selenium

I want to read WebPageId in following script by using java.

Could you please help me out.

**Function:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    try{_paq.push(["setSid", 8]);
            _paq.push(["setSid","environment"]);
                (function () {
                var configarray = ['www.xyz.com'];
                if (configarray.indexOf(window.location.hostname)!=-1)

                               {_paq.push(['setCVariable','1','webPageId',12345,'page']);
_paq.push(["trackPageView"]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable to a javascript that **returns** using this syntax:

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
} // else throw...

// later on...
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('someId');");
```